# How to measure the failure of Hasse norm theorem?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

We know that the failure the [unique factorisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorisation) is measured by the [ideal class-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group), that of the [local-global principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local-global_principle) depends upon the [Tate-Shafarevich group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%E2%80%93Shafarevich_group).

> Then I thought: what should be the right tool to detect the failure of the [Hasse-norm theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_norm_theorem)?
>   Also, when does the Hasse-norm theorem hold, apart from the cyclic cases?

I know almost nothing in this direction, so any reference or indication are the most appreciated; thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this is something for MathOverflow?

Comment: But I think this shows no real research effort. It resembles more like a curiosity-oriented question rather than a real obstacle that I encountered during a research. And this is exactly why I started using stack exchange ratheer than overflow: I don't see any research in my questions. :P Q__Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure of Hasse's norm theorem is measured by Scholz's knots. See in particular Jehne's beautiful article "On knots in algebraic number theory"
over [here](https://eudml.org/doc/152174) and the discussion 
[here](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/pcft.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for this interesting paper and discussion. Quite surprised to find out Sholz's results. :)